# Can someone explain what Genevieve was going to originally do in Rush Hour 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, rush-hour-3

There is a scene in *Ruch Hour 3* where Genevieve is in bed with Carter.

[image]

Later on because Lee startles them and the assassin enters the room it ends up turning into this:

[image]

However prior to actually being startled Genevieve was already reaching for her gun. What was her motives? Was she planning to kill Carter? If so then why does she stick around afterwards. If she didn't want to be around Lee and Carter she could've left after this incident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I think you will find that although we the audience did not know about the assassin *she* knew about the assassin because she had the names tattooed on hear head and lots of people were trying to kill her.

It was just a build up to the assassin jumping into our view  on screen. A moment of "Oh no Carter!" then "Phew! It was just an assassin!".

Comment: That would seem to be the answer. Otherwise it just comes off as she was going to kill Carter.